# How to get Arch Linux OS on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: software-installation, archlinux, storage

So, I was going to get Arch Linux on my Raspberry Pi as a test, and so I plugged the microSD card into my laptop. It's a Dell Latitude E6230 running Windows 10. Turns out it counted at like 5 different drives? Does anybody know how to completely format the microSD? If so, thank you so much in advance!

Edited to include image:

[image]

Comment: What does "Turns out it counted at like 5 different drives?" mean? What laptop?

Comment: It's a Dell Latitude E6230 running Windows 10. [This](https://imgur.com/a/2mjYgbA) is what I mean by "5 different drives"

Comment: If you want anyone to read your post include detail **in the question** - preferably as text. There are so many things missing from your post - like **WHAT** you did or tried.

Comment: The bottom line seems to be that nowadays you need a working LINUX system that can reformat and write the SD card with the ext4 filesystems/partitions that are needed for the ARCHLINUX version of Linux. This will likely rule out the average PC that is only running a Windoze OS.

Comment: Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE. I'm editing my answer based on Millway's comment. I agree with others here that you need to include more information about what you tried. [These appear to be the instructions for Arch for the raspberry pi, armv6.](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi) Also though, I would suggest a different linux distribution for you. With Arch linux you are basically expected to know how to figure things like this out for yourself.

Comment: The problem with this "Answer" is the `Download the image` step. The is NO image for Arch!

You are not helping anyone by posting answers to poor ill-defined questions.

Comment: @Milliways good point, I read too fast and missed that it was Arch. But if you knew that, you could have pointed the user to some instructions. They're new and I don't think it hurts to try to help.

Comment: There are no instructions for Arch which work for current models. Installing it is a black art, and requires a Linux OS. It is far from clear from the question what the OP is actually doing, and has not clarified.

Answer (score 1):

I have that not 1 drive too. I have two drivers but it's he same with your problem.
When you installing ARCH LINUX to microsd(burn) Arch linux dividing microsd by 5 sectors. One of them are boot that you can see files in it. But 4 drives you cannot see because they are in different type drive that WINDOWS not able to read.(not exFat,Fat16/32/64/...). When you click them they are seeing thet you must format microsd. Don't do it! It will work.